# Creating new raster based on spatial extent and classes of one raster and average of another using ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, zonal-statistics

I have a raster that is split into classes and I wanted to make a new raster with this raster's spatial extent and classes but displaying the average values from a different raster.

How do I do this?

Comment: Can you edit your question to clarify what you mean by 'averages from a different raster'? It sounds to me like you wan the Zonal Statistics tool - your class raster is your zones and your 'different' raster is what you'll run the statistics on.

Comment: Thank you @ChrisW I have just tried that and it worked! Exactly what I wanted to do.

Answer (score 1):

There are several [environment settings](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/What_is_a_geoprocessing_environment_setting/001w00000034000000/) that affect raster operations. In this instance you should be setting:

- [Output Extent](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Output_Extent/001w00000009000000/) - to ensure that the new raster will be of the
  same size.
- [Snap Raster](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001w0000000m000000) - to the raster to match with, this ensures the
  cells line up exactly.
- [Cell Size](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Cell_Size/001w0000001s000000/) - to make the output raster the same cell size as the
  one you're matching to.

All of these can be set to the existing raster dataset to match their particular aspects of raster properties.

I think you are trying to do this using the toolbox, select the existing raster dataset for these three settings; if you are unsure about setting environments then read [this section about setting environments](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Setting_geoprocessing_environments/001w0000003s000000/) for the toolbox.

Answer (score 1):

The [Zonal Statistics](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z000000w7000000) tool is the one you want. Your classification raster will be your zones and your 'different' raster will be the input for the statistics. It will calculate the average value of the cells from each zone and create a new raster that looks like your classed raster but has the average values instead of class values in the data. Note this would be the same as running Reclassify on your classed raster, assuming you knew what the average values you needed to input were.